# Finding $g$ such that $(f(g(x)))'=1$ when $f:[-1,1]\to S$

Tags: derivatives

This is probably a simple question, but had a little trouble figuring it out, so hopefully someone here knows how to do it. Suppose $f:[-1,1]\to S$, where $S$ is some set endowed with a nonnegative symmetric distance function $d$. Define a "derivative" of $f$ by
$$\partial_d[f(x)]=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{d(f(x+h),f(x))}{h}.$$
Note that $\partial_d[f(x)]\geq0$. I would like to find a monotone-increasing function $g:[-1,1]\to[-1,1]$ such that
$$\partial_d[f(g(x))]=c$$
where $c$ is some constant, with $g(-1)=-1$ and $g(1)=1$ (ie, $g$ is a monotone bijection from $[-1,1]$ to itself).

My question is:

- How do I find an expression for $g$?

For simplicity, assume that $0<\partial_d[f(x)]<\infty$ to avoid any ugly issues with singularities.

Comment: The limit $h\to0^+$ makes no sense at $x=1$.

Comment: @ajotatxe: Yeah, I guess in that case you can just ignore boundary issues, as I was planning on implementing this numerically and the interior region is more important, so issues with the boundaries can be ignored.

Comment: @ajotatxe: In other words, this is not meant to be rigorous.